# How do I set a select box value using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I have the following select box inside my `form_tag`.

```
<select name="sel">
  <option selected=true value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="*">*</option>
  <option value="/">/</option>
</select>
```

How do I set the option for a select box in the controller? Also, how do I retain the selected option even after submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select and retain a default value, one possibility is:

```
<%= select_tag "sel", "<option>+</option><option selected='selected'>-</option><option>*</option><option>/</option>".html_safe %>
```

If you want to retain a value that was previously selected, you need to save it somewhere and make it available in your controller, say in a @previously_selected variable, then:

```
select_tag "whatever", options_for_select([ "+", "-", "*", "/" ], @previously_selected)
```

Comment: why not use `options_for_select` helper?

Comment: @Miotsu The value changes once I give submit . I want the select box to retain the selected value .

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= select_tag "sel", options_for_select([['+', '+'], ['-','-'], ['*','*'],['/','/']], params[:sel] || '*')
```

Comment: Is it possible to display `*` for the first time and then retain the selected values for the submits . ? The order of options should not change , but just need to display `*` as the selected option for the first time .

Comment: I tried the updated answer it didn't work shows `-` instead .